# Lock threads in Python for a task

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program that uses threads to start another thread once a certain threshold is reached. Right now  the second thread is being started multiple times. I implemented a lock but I don't think I did it right.

```
for i in range(max_threads):
    t1 = Thread(target=grab_queue)
    t1.start()
```

in grab_queue, I have:

...

```
   rows.append(resultJson)
    if len(rows.value()) >= 250:
        with Lock():
            row_thread = Thread(target=insert_rows, kwargs={'rows': rows.value()})
            row_thread.start()
            rows.reset()
```

Which starts another thread to process the list of rows. I would like to make sure that as soon as it hits the if condition, the other threads wont run in order to make sure that extra threads to process the list of rows aren't started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock is covering the wrong portion of the code. You have a race condition between the check for the size of rows, and the portion of the code where you reset the rows. Given that the lock is taken only *after* the size check, two threads could easily both decide that the array has grown too large, and only then would the lock kick in to serialize the resetting of the array. "Serialize" in this case means that the task would still be performed twice, once by each thread, but it would happen in succession rather than in parallel.

The correct code could look like this:

```
rows.append(resultJson)
with grow_lock:
    if len(rows.value()) >= 250:
        row_thread = Thread(target=insert_rows, kwargs={'rows': rows.value()})
        row_thread.start()
        rows.reset()
```

There is another issue with the code as shown in the question: if `Lock()` refers to `threading.Lock`, it is creating and locking a new lock on each invocation, and in each thread! A lock protects a resource shared among threads, and to perform that function, the lock must itself be shared. To fix the problem, instantiate the lock once and pass it to the thread's target function.

Taking a step back, your code implements a custom thread pool. Getting that right and covering all the corner cases takes a lot of work, testing, and debugging. There are production-tested modules specialized for that purpose, such as the `multiprocessing` module shipped with Python (which supports both process and thread pools), and it is a good idea to get acquainted with them before reimplementing their functionality. See, for example, [this article](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/) for an accessible introduction to `multiprocessing`-based thread pools.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the second part? I am indeed using threading.lock. Do you mean just instantiate a lock at the start of my program and pass it as a parameter to my threads?

Comment: @Wilson If you instantiate the lock at the start of the program, you can as well hold it in a global variable. Ideally you would instantiate the lock at the same place where you create `rows`. Avoiding global variables makes it possible for multiple thread pools that don't know about each others to exist. Also, learn about the [thread pool support provided by the multiprocessing module](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/), as advertised in the amended answer.